# Hadith on believers being asked about their luxuries in this world

Tags: hadith, source-identification, reference-request

Is anyone able to please help me find the hadith in which Rasoolullah SAW stated that the believers will be asked about each luxury they have had in this world, even a cold glass of water?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. I'm afraid we need some more information. With the given input I was not able to find any hadith saying so however there's a hadith showing that wasting water for wudu' is rather frowned upon. But this seems far fetched.

Comment: Walaykum Asalaam wa Rahmatullah. Yes, of course. My apologies for paraphrasing, but the hadith that I was searching for is where one of the companions (RA) had asked the Prophet ﷺ about if mankind will be asked about the luxuries they experienced in this world, and the Prophet responded yes. He then goes on to state that one of the luxuries he enjoyed was a cup of cold water on a warm day.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have this in mind:

> إن أول ما يسأل عنه يوم القيامة - يعني العبد من النعيم - أن يقال له: ألم نصح لك جسمك، ونرويك من الماء البارد
>
> Indeed the first of what will be asked about on the Day of Judgment – meaning the slave (of Allah) being questioned about the favors – is that it will be said to him: ‘Did We not make your body, health, and give you of cool water to drink?
>
> <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/744090)</sup>

It is narrated in the exegesis of the verse:

> ثم لتسألن يومئذ عن النعيم
>
> Then you will surely be asked that Day about pleasure.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 102:8](http://quran.com/102/8)</sup>